# Accessing a global variable that is been updated from an asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, arrays

i'm really struggling to understand the asynchronous side of JavaScript. the code i have is meant to collate specific details of certain users and then put all the collated information into a global variable array which i intent to manipulate when all the users have been added to the array. i'm finding it difficult to iterate the array because when i do an array.length on the printurlonPage() function i get a 0 despite the fact that when i do a console log on the array itself i can see that there are items there. Does anyone know a technique that allows me to work on the global variable only after the asynchronous function has completed?

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var PeopleCompleteList = []; 



function PersonConstructor(username,Title,Phone,Email,imageurl){

    return {
        name: username,
        Title: Title,
        phoneNumber: Phone,
        Email: Email,
        Picture: imageurl

    }

}

var printurlonPage = function (){
    
        for (var link in PeopleCompleteList) {
            console.log(link['Picture']);
        }
    console.log(PeopleCompleteList);
}

var getIndividualPersonDetails = function(GetPictureUrl) {
    listName = 'TeamInfo';
    //var PeopleCompleteList = []; 
             

        // execute AJAX request
        $.ajax({
             url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listName+"')/items?$select=Name/Title,Name/Name,Name/Id,Name/EMail,Name/WorkPhone&$expand=Name/Id",
            type: "GET",
            headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {

                for (i=0; i< data.d.results.length; i++) {
                    //check if the user exists if he does store the following properties name,title,workphone,email and picture url
                    if(data.d.results[i]['Name'] != null){
                        var personName = data.d.results[i]['Name'].Name.split('|')[2];
                        var userName = data.d.results[i]['Name']['Name'];
                        var UserTitle = data.d.results[i]['Name']['Title'];
                        var UserphoneNumber = data.d.results[i]['Name']['WorkPhone'];
                        var UserEmail = data.d.results[i]['Name']['EMail'];
                        var myuserPicture = GetPictureUrl(userName);
                        console.log(myuserPicture);
                        PeopleCompleteList.push(PersonConstructor(personName, UserTitle, UserphoneNumber,UserEmail,myuserPicture));
                    } 
                }
                    
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Failed to get details");
              
            }
        });
        
    }

function GetPictureUrl(user) {
    
            var userPicture="";
            var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
                             "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='"+encodeURIComponent(user)+"'";

                     $.ajax({
                            url: requestUri,
                            type: "GET",
                            async:false,
                            headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
                            success: function (data) {
                                console.log(data);
                               
                              var PictureDetails = data.d.PictureUrl != null ? data.d.PictureUrl : 'c:\apps\noimageurl.jpg';
                              userPicture=PictureDetails;
                            }

                       });
                return userPicture;

};

$(function () {
 getIndividualPersonDetails(GetPictureUrl);
    printurlonPage();
});


</script>
```

Comment: Async function may have call back or try to use Promise

Comment: No dont make it global. Pass the array from callback to callback...

Comment: thanks Jonas, your approach worked, i declared the variable on the getIndividualPersonDetails and passed the printurlonPage function as a callback.

Answer (score 1):

You're printurlonPage() is not asynchronous, so it's running before getIndividualPersonDetails responds. You can do two things, use promises or use async/await from es7. I prefer async/await, but you'll need to babelify.

Or, you can just put your printurlonPage invocation inside your success: handler.

```
    success: function (data) {

        for (i=0; i< data.d.results.length; i++) {
            //check if the user exists if he does store the following properties name,title,workphone,email and picture url
            if(data.d.results[i]['Name'] != null){
                var personName = data.d.results[i]['Name'].Name.split('|')[2];
                var userName = data.d.results[i]['Name']['Name'];
                var UserTitle = data.d.results[i]['Name']['Title'];
                var UserphoneNumber = data.d.results[i]['Name']['WorkPhone'];
                var UserEmail = data.d.results[i]['Name']['EMail'];
                var myuserPicture = GetPictureUrl(userName);
                console.log(myuserPicture);
                PeopleCompleteList.push(PersonConstructor(personName, UserTitle, UserphoneNumber,UserEmail,myuserPicture));
            } 
        }
        printurlonPage();

    },
```

And then in document.ready:

```
$(function () {
    getIndividualPersonDetails(GetPictureUrl);
});
```

So, getIndividualPersonDetails is invoked, and then when it receives the data, the callback is invoked with the data.